# Swift/XCode - Check value of JSON Data And Determine Output

Tags: ios, json

I am currently working on a small project. I am trying to do the following, in essence:

- Check the value of a certain key i.e. "color"
- Depending on the value of this key, I wish to display a certain
  image from my assets folder.

How can I do this?

Example:

if the `color` key is equal to `green`, display a green image within the `UIImageView` from my `Assets` folder.

Hope someone can help me :).

Comment: ImageView.Image = UIImage(named: json["color"].stringValue) assuming you have already your json object and using SwiftyJson. If not post your code

Comment: Correct, I am using SwiftyJson and AlamoFire. I understand what you have done here, however, where do I set the image? I've got the key value ["color"] but depending on the key, I wish to assign a certain image.

Comment: I don't agree with @Dima, have a look on his score, instead of a punch you could help him understand not only how Swift works but also how the community works.

Comment: @GIJOW What are you talking about, I just removed the Xcode tag.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your image is called in your assets, assuming you have the image named :

> redCat

In your json you have the value key "red" in your node color. Then to set your image will be:

```
let imageName = String(format: "%@Cat", json["color"].stringValue)
yourImageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
```

But, you have several ways to do that, inside main thread, background, from network, etc. So it depends on your implementation and how your images are named inside your asset.

Next time, post your code and a better description to avoid having your question being negativated.

Comment: Oh I'm such an idiot. I forgot to mention, I am using an API.

Comment: I suggest you to research a lit bit more. You are far away from your objective and giving small pieces (hints) each time will not help you. Or you post a real question, with code, explanations and why you can't reach your goal or nobody will help you